# how to change the status bar color to transparent for splash screen using nativescript?

Tags: nativescript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEZBE.png)How to change the status bar icon color for splash screen (LaunchScreenTheme) in android ?

I tried the below code but it's not working .

```
<color name="ns_ThemeBase">#FFFFFF</color>

<style name="LaunchScreenTheme" parent="LaunchScreenThemeBase">
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>  
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ns_ThemeBase</item>
    </style>
```

How to change the status bar background to white and the icons to black ?

Comment: Possible solution https://egghead.io/lessons/angular-2-modify-status-bar-colors-on-ios-and-android-with-nativescript

Comment: Another approach https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-statusbar

Comment: The code is working fine for Home screen but not for the splash screen.

Comment: I am not able to change the color for status bar icons for splash screen.

Comment: The code is not working for Launch screen.

Answer (score 4):

If it helps, I wasn't able to make status bar transparent, my workaround is to hide it.

Try to add those two lines in your style :

```
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

You should have this (`styles.xml`) :

```
<!-- Launch Screen -->
<style name="LaunchScreenTheme" parent="LaunchScreenThemeBase">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ns_ThemeBase</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Working example : https://github.com/mickaeleuranie/nativescript-stackoverflow-49236235

How it looks : [image: https://imgur.com/y2QXvlI]

Answer (score 2):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WASpA.png)

This is what i actually looked for and i achieved it by using the code

```
<style name="LaunchScreenTheme" parent="LaunchScreenThemeBase">
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>  
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ns_ThemeBase</item>
    </style>
```

Thanks for all your support , Cheers :)